# Extract a column from a multidemsional array

Tags: perl

I have a multidimensional array

```
my @multi = ( [ 1, "first", "a" ], [ 2, "second", b ], [ 3, "third", c] ... );
```

I want to extract a single dimensional array of:

```
[ "first", "second", "third" ... ]
```

These would be a combination of the references to @multi[0][1], @multi[1][1] , @multi[2][1] ...

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[ map { $_->[1] } @multi ]
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, you might do it like this:

```
use strict;

my @multi = ( [ 1, "first", "a" ], [ 2, "second", "b" ], [ 3, "third", "c" ] );
my $res;

push @$res, $_->[1] for @multi;

use Data::Dump;
dd $res;
```

Output:

```
["first", "second", "third"]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Array of array

This is fully explained at `perldoc perllol`, `man perllol` or [perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

You could dereference your array variable:

```
map { ${$_}[1] } @multi
```

Another syntax for the same thing:

```
map { $_->[1] } @multi
```

try:

```
my @multi = ( [ 1, "first", "a" ], [ 2, "second", b ], [ 3, "third", c] );
print join(", ", map { ${ $_ }[1] } @multi)."\n";
print join(", ", map { $_->[1] } @multi)."\n";
```

#### And

```
use Data::Dumper;
my @multi = ( [ 1, "first", "a" ], [ 2, "second", b ], [ 3, "third", c] );
my @other=( [ 1 , undef , "A" ] , [ 2 , [ map { ${$_}[1] } @multi ], "B" ] );
$Data::Dumper::Indent= 0;
print Data::Dumper->Dump([\@other],[qw|other|])."\n";
```

will render:

```
$other = [[1,undef,'A'],[2,['first','second','third'],'B']];
```

Where...

```
$other = [[1,undef,"A"],[2,["first","second","third"],"B"]];
print $other->[0]->[0]."\n";
print $other->[1]->[0]."\n";
print $other->[1]->[1]->[0]."\n";
print $other->[1]->[1]->[2]."\n";
print $other->[1]->[2]."\n";
```

could give:

```
1
2
first
third
B
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use de-reference:

```
my @multi = ( [ 1, "first", "a" ], [ 2, "second", b ], [ 3, "third", c]);
my $index = 0;
my @single;
foreach (@multi) {
    my $aref = $multi[$index];
    $single[$index] = $aref->[1];
    $index++;
}
print "\n @single \n";
```

Output:
`first second third`

Comment: It would be better to use push: `push @single, $aref->[1];`

Comment: Okey. I am still new to perl and just read about references. Could you provide an explanation as to why push would be better?

Comment: Because you almost never need to iterate an array index in perl, and so it's not a well used idiom. I think stylistically it's not as 'nice' either. For example - in the above: `foreach my $aref ( @multi ) { push @single, $aref ->[1]; }` will accomplish the  same thing, without needing to bother with the extra variables.

Comment: @manpreet bhamba: To get you to think of arrays as a class. This makes it easier to think about working with arrays as a single entity. For example, you can use arrays as double-ended queues (deq) <http://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2012/11/a-look-at-arrays.html>. All the methods for deqs can be implemented with one line in Perl.

Comment: Thank you Sobrique & Shawn for explaining.